# How to remove empty Datetime entries of Symfony form Collection ? (delete_emply not working)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, datetime, collections

I am using a Symfony form with a collection of Datetime entries. How can I remove the empty datetime entries from the collection when the form is submitted?

I have set **delete_empty** to *true* but it is not working. I am trying hard to follow the doc instructions
(https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#delete-empty) but I must be missing something somewhere.
I have also tried the **required** option to *false* and **empty_data** to *null*.
Should I write a callable that check if datetime is empty? If so how to check if a datetime is empty?

Here is my form builder code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($event)
            ->add('datetimes', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => DateTimeType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                    'input' => 'string',
                    'time_widget' => 'single_text',
                    'html5' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'empty_data' => null,
                ],
                'label' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => false,
                'delete_empty' => true
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try the calable? it can help you to deal with complex conditions of saying that the value is null

Comment: dump the value of this field, to check if it is setting your field to null

Comment: @hoover_D what’s the callable doing exactly? I did not understand it really ...

Comment: @hoover_D actually the callable did the work, thanks for your help

Comment: thanks! can I add this as answer for you to check?